# How to achieve Enable/Disable command with Task-pane in Officejs

Tags: office-js

We are trying to implement feature enable/disable add-in commands in Excel add-in. 
It is enabled **shared runtime** for task-pane based on reference   **https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/disable-add-in-commands**
 When we are trying with task-pane configuration in manifest, feature is not working as expected. it is behaving based on taskpanid how it is being set in ShowTaskPane tags. For example if it is having common TaskpaneId for multiple taskpanes then getting error as "Error in manifest file" when trying to upload manifest file with shared runtime. As another option if it is having unique TaskpaneId for multiple taskpanes it could be able to upload the manifest file but in right side of taskpane, icons with down arrow getting binded for each click of taskpane commands with shared runtime. Hence required the samples/clarifications for configuring multiple taskpanes with shared runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to have more than one task pane open at the same time in your add-in? That cannot be done at this time. For security reasons, Office allows a shared runtime in an add-in to have only one task pane open at at time.

Comment: Do you mean if we have taskpane1.html and taspane2.html in manifest then shared runtime can apply only one of the taskpane.....can you please provide the option to share   my manifest file for your review so that you can correct me if anything wrong....Or is this case only for shared runtime?..

Comment: No runtime, even if its not shared, can have more than one window open at a time. Please see the [Script Lab](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/wa104380862) tool. It has two task panes called "Code" and "Run". When you open one and then open the other, the first one closes and becomes a button on the right side of the task pane area.

Comment: Ok. Thanks Rick. Presently am providing unique TaskpaneId so that it is getting opened one window at a time. The Scenario here it is having 3 task-panes'. As you said when i open second task pane first one getting closed and becomes a button on the right side of the task pane area. But when i trying to open first task pane again it is getting opened with previously binded data without refreshing. Do i need to have to refresh the task-pane so that it can be opened with updated data.?

Comment: Hi Rick. Can you provide your suggestion or if anything need to correct.... Can you provide the options to share manifest for your code review?

Comment: I think your scenario would be easier to accomplish with a single task pane that has multiple tabs within it. If you add your manifest (after removing private data and GUIDs) to your question, I will take a brief look, but code reviews aren't really what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: I have raised in github with Manifest file and summarized these scenarios. Kindly help me out. Thanks